# Java Generics and return types

Tags: java, generics

I just ran into something that I do not understand. Why isn't the for each loop below legal when the second identically one is?

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {
   List<SomeNamedObject> getObjects();
   void doSomething(P1 p1, T p2);
}

public class SomeNamedObject {
    private String text;
}

public class Clazz {

    private SomeInterface someInterface;

    ...

    public void someMethod() {
       // Error Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to TestClass.SomeNamedObject
       for (SomeNamedObject someNamedObject :  someInterface.getObjects()) {
             // This loop won't compile as the someInterface.getObjects returns just a List and not a List<SomeNamedObject>
       }

       // Warning Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked 
       // conversion to conform to List<TestClass.SomeNamedObject>
       List<SomeNamedObject> objects = someInterface.getObjects();
       for (SomeNamedObject someNamedObject :  objects) {
             // This loop compiles 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bug, its a problem with erasure and raw types.

Comment: I don't see what the problem might be.  Can you post the actual stack trace (just the first few lines).  I'm guessing your full class requires "SomeInterface<T>", but the example does not require the "<T>"  Perhaps there is something in there?

Comment: @Jay his declaration of someInterface doesnt specify the generic type, Java then falls back to raw types and the method signature changes to returning a raw List(see answers). He should have mentioned the warning on the objects assignment tho.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because your instance variable `private SomeInterface someInterface` doesn't specify its generic type parameter then all use of generics is disabled for `someInterface`. This means that `someInterface.getObjects()` has the raw return type `List` rather than `List<SomeNamedObject>`. This is the reason the first example does not compile.

In the second example `List<SomeNamedObject> objects = someInterface.getObjects()` is putting in an explicit type for the list. You will see a warning when you do this though  because the type safety is not guaranteed. This is the same behaviour you would see if `getObjects()` was defined as just `List getObjects()` without the type parameter.

Comment: It may be a typo in the original, but `SomeInterface<T>` doesn't use `T` to specify the generic type for the `List` being returned, that's hard-coded as `SomeNamedObject`.  So, even though the instance variable isn't typed, it shouldn't affect the returned `List`.

Comment: If the generic parameter is not specified in the declaration of `someInterface` then *all* generics types in `SomeInterface` are ignored/disabled even if they don't depend on `T`.

Comment: Very interesting, although peculiar.

Answer (score 3):

You should note that you get a compiler warning when you asign to objects before the second loop.

```
Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to 
 List<TestClass.SomeNamedObject>
```

This would have told you that for some reason your getObjects() method is returning a non generified List. Which explains why the first loop does not compile.

Because you forgot to generify your reference:

```
private SomeInterface someInterface;
```

If you dont generify it everything will use the raw type, including the signature of the declared method. Means it returns a raw List object instead of a List<SomeNamedObject>
Do something like

```
private SomeInterface<Object> someInterface;
```

And it should work.